# Socket Write Failure when sending File

Tags: c++, image, file, sockets, buffer

I've been stuck on this issue for awhile where I'm unable to send a file through a socket. I've sent other information just fine using this method, but the problem seems to appear when I try to send a PNG file as a string.

These are the methods I use to to send and receive information:

```
// Sends a Message to the specified Socket
void Server::sendMessage(int socket, string message)
{
    // Write the Message Size to the Socket
    send(socket, itoa((message.length() + 1)), sizeof(size_t));

    // Wait for Write Confirmation
    bool response;
    receive(socket, &response, 2);

    // Write the Message to the Socket
    send(socket, (char*) message.c_str(), message.length() + 1);

    // Wait for Write Confirmation
    receive(socket, &response, 2);
}

// Receives Message from the specified Socket
string Server::receiveMessage(int socket)
{
    // Read the Message Size from the Socket
    int size;
    receive(socket, &size, sizeof(size_t));

    // Send Write Confirmation
    send(socket, itoa(true), 2);

    // Receive the Message from the Socket
    char message[size];
    receive(socket, message, size);

    // Send Write Confirmation
    send(socket, itoa(true), 2);

    // Return the Message as a String
    string msg(message);
    return msg;
}
```

The **send** and **receive** methods are just relays for **write** and **read** respectively. I'm only doing error checking in those methods, and it's the **send** method that's telling me that the **write** isn't working. In case it matters, this is my **send** method:

```
// Sends a Data Packet to the specified Socket
int Server::send(int socket, void* data, int size)
{
    // Write the Data to the Socket
    int count = write(socket, data, size);

    // Make sure the Write Succeeded
    if(count == -1)
    {
            print("$f1Error: $f0Unable to Write to Socket $t1%i$t0\n", socket);
            exit(1);
    }

    return count;
}
```

I should note that the Server operates as a Thread, therefore the above three functions are static. The Client also contains the same four networking functions.

The command line breaking this happens in a separate static function which I use to handle Clients. Here is the relevant portion of said method:

```
// Handles each Client with a Thread 
void* Server::server_handleClient(void* arg)
{
    // Determine the Socket Descriptor
    int socket = *((int*) arg);
    free(arg);

    // Create the Rover
    Rover* rover = new Rover();

    // Loop Indefinitely
    while(true)
    {
        ...
        // Take a Picture and Send it
        sendMessage(socket, rover -> takePicture());
        ...
    }

    // Delete the Rover
    delete rover;

    // Close the Socket
    close(socket);

    // Return a Successful Status
    return (void*) new int(0);
}
```

Here you can see that I make use of a method from another class I've created. Here is the **takePicture** method from the **Rover** class, which is where I actually grab the picture:

```
// Takes a Picture and Returns the Photo as a String
inline string Rover::takePicture()
{
    // Open the Picture File
    ifstream picture;
    string filepath = "./Server/Pictures/" + getDirection() + ".png";
    picture.open(filepath.c_str());

    // Make sure the File Opened
    if(!picture.is_open())
            return "";

    // Read the File into a String Buffer
    stringstream buffer;
    buffer << picture.rdbuf();

    return buffer.str();
}
```

So in short, the **Server** gets a picture from the **Rover** which it then sends to a **Client**. When I check the contents of the string for the photo, it's all there. All possible photos are reasonable in size *(the photo used for testing is 674,962 bytes, and the buffer size sent is 674,963 which is expected)*.

I've used these methods for sending various messages, and all of that worked fine. I'm able to send strings *(Like "Hello World!")* and integers just fine.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Is the file that I'm trying to send simply too large? Is there some information that I'm missing? I need help...

---

**Edit:**
I've made a few changes with a little progress. I made one small change to the **sendMessage** command. The current problem is that the picture isn't being sent properly.

New **sendMessage** function:

```
// Sends a Message to the specified Socket
void Server::sendMessage(int socket, string message, bool data = false)
{
        // Write the Message Size to the Socket
        send(socket, itoa((message.length() + 1)), sizeof(size_t));

        // Wait for Write Confirmation
        bool response;
        receive(socket, &response, 2);

        // Determine the Type of Data to Send
        if(data)
        {
                // Write the Message Data to the Socket
                send(socket, (char*) message.data(), message.length() + 1);
        }
        else
        {
                // Write the Message to the Socket
                send(socket, (char*) message.c_str(), message.length() + 1);
        }

        // Wait for Write Confirmation
        receive(socket, &response, 2);
}
```

The Client's copy of this function has been updated to match as well.

Now that we're working on getting the PNG file saved, here's the function that deals with that as well:

```
// Handles each Client with a Thread 
void* Client::client_handleServer(void* arg)
{
        // Define Socket Variables
        int socket = *((int*) arg);
        free(arg);

        ...
        // Export the Picture to the Client's Directory
        message = receiveMessage(socket);
        ofstream picture;
        picture.open("./Client/Pictures/Picture.png", std::ifstream::binary);
        picture << message;
        picture.close();
        ...
}
```

Comment: you haven't described what happens to the picture on the client side? why are you sending message.length() + 1?

Comment: I send the message length before sending the message so that the other system knows how much to read.

As for the picture on the client side, the write on the server side fails, so the client never receives it. The code shows this, as the error only occurs if the byte count written to the socket is -1 (meaning the write failed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured everything out in the long run.

Pictures are binary files, and I was using Strings which use ASCII Characters. The issue with this is that binary data does not always translate to ASCII, and Strings are terminated by null characters, whereas binary data can contain null data within it. Long story short, strings do not work.

To preserve the message handling I had in place, I ended up just converting the binary data to hexadecimal data (0-F) which could be displayed in a String.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are opening the file in textmode. that means any characters in the files which contain newlines "\n" are converted to new line + carriage returns "\r\n".

Open your file in binary mode, like so

```
picture.open(filepath.c_str(), std::ifstream::binary);
```

then it may work.

Comment: I tried this, and made a little bit a progress. The write no longer fails, but only 8 bytes are being transfered (The server is still sending the proper amount). When I check the string being sent, it contains this: "%PNG[]\n\n\0". The '[]' is just a box symbol counting as one character. If I try to open the picture in Paint, it says that the PNG is not a valid format, and it cannot read it.

Comment: // Write the Message to the Socket
    send(socket, (char*) message.c_str(), message.length() + 1); dont convert to c_str(). use message.data() instead. message.c_str() converts it into a null terminated C String.

Comment: Just tried this. The output is mildly different, and the picture still isn't properly transferred. The message being sent is now "‰PNG\n[]\n\0". Just a one character difference (I had misplaced the first \n).

Comment: and you need to define your stringstream as so buffer(std::ios::binary);

Comment: Now the string being sent contains zero bytes. I've also added the changes to the **sendMessage** function and the portion of code I'm using to save the picture to the OP. Hopefully that helps further.

Comment: I can't see your recv function completely but the problem may be the that the recv std::string accepts your char array and then stops at the first null character in the string. the other possibilty would be to instantiate the recv string so string (const char* s, size_t n); btw were you successful at some point in sending all bytes? and the problem was only at the recv end?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42537/discussion-between-goldcode-and-boom)

Answer (score 1):

```
void Server::sendMessage(int socket, string message)
```

The problem is right here. Don't use `string` as a container for binary data. Pass the image around as a byte array. Same applies to this:

```
string Server::receiveMessage(int socket)
```